# wp_query for category and custom post type together

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to make one loop with categories (1,8) and custom post type (promotions) but it's not work.
This is My query

```
$args = array (
'post_type' => array( 'promotions' ),
'category__in' => array(1,8),
'posts_per_page' => -1,
);
$queryconfig = new WP_Query( $args );

<?php while ( $queryconfig->have_posts() ) : $queryconfig->the_post(); ?> 

            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
            <span> <?php the_title() ?></span>
            </a>

    <?php endwhile;?>

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

What should I do? How join category and custom post type in one loop?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.
table of args should look like this:

```
$args = array(
                        'post_type' => array('post', 'promotions', 'other_custom_post_type'),
                        'posts_per_page' => -1,
                        'category__not_in' => array(1,8),

                    );
```

post_type "post" include all categories and category__not_in exclude what we do not want